# iOS - Wireless Ad-hoc distribution

Tags: ios, iphone, ad-hoc-distribution

I used Ad-hoc provision profile to export a IPA with manifest file for testers download from my web server. I uploaded .ipa, .plist, images and index.html to a server location,

Like this:

> /var/www/html/apps/DemoPad.ipa
>
> /var/www/html/apps/manifest.plist
>
> /var/www/html/apps/image.png
>
> /var/www/html/apps/image-full.jpg
>
> /var/www/html/apps/index.html

I send a url to testers like this (https://www.example.com/apps/index.html)

But when open in iphone browser (Safari) to download, it prompts a message "Cannot connect to www.example.com"

Here is the plist contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://www.example.com/apps/DemoPad.ipa</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://www.example.com/apps/image.png</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://www.example.com/apps/image-full.jpg</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.example.webpad</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>DemoPad</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is my Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.example.com/apps/manifest.plist">Install</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone advise me how to resolve it?

Comment: Why don't you just use `TestFlight`? It will be easier to maintain, distribute, and get feedback from testers.

Comment: Because my client requests.